# Change height contraint layout dynamically

Tags: java, android

SITUATION:

[x] List Item / Toggle Headline

- Sub List item
- Sub List item

[ ] List Item / Toggle Headline

*How can I dymanically change the height of the first list item depending if its checkbox is checked or not?*

(If checkbox is checked it opens a sub list)

**So how can I change the height of a contraint layout with coding?**

PS: I am using AndroidStudio 3.2

Comment: great, that solved it! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @LeoAso if you want to get a higher reputation here on stack overflow, type your answer below as a "new answer" and I will give you the check so you will get 15 reputation points ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to change the height dynamically. Just put the sublist inside a ViewGroup like LinearLayout and toggle the visibility between `View.VISIBLE` and `View.GONE` when the checkbox changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can change **height** or **width** **every views** with this codes :

```
private void changeIncludes (View newView ){
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) newView.getLayoutParams();
        // change width and height to 50
        params.height = 50 ;
        params.width = 50;
        newView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

or use from other view size :

```
private void changeIncludes (View current , View newView ){
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) newView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = current.getLayoutParams().height;
        params.width = current.getLayoutParams().width;
        newView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

if width or height not change you should refresh page .

This codes work for me , I hope work for you too .

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){
                    changeIncludes(buttonView,50,100);
                }else{
                    changeIncludes(buttonView,30,100);
                }
            }
        });

private void changeIncludes (View newView , int h , int w){
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) newView.getLayoutParams();
        // change width and height to 50
        params.height = h ;
        params.width = w;
        newView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

I use this codes for an check box , but if you want use for an list item , you just should change listener and interface .

Answer (score 0):

Depending what kind of `ViewGroup`s you are using you can set visibility of these groups based on what is checked.

For example, if you are using `ConstraintLayout`, you get a pretty handy `android.support.constraint.Group`. In this case,

```
<android.support.constraint.Group
    android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="sub_list_item_1,sub_list_item_2" />
```

Then, as you detect checkbox interaction, set the visibility of it (`View.Visible` or `View.GONE`).

```
Group group1 = findViewById(R.id.group)
group1.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```